# Pull portion of web page from a page hosted on another server

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a company site that's hosted on a separate server from the main site.  So, for example, I'm working on guest.company.com, and the main company website is www.company.com, and the two sites are hosted on different servers (and different development solutions).

The project I'm working on has a copy of the css from the main site, and has a shared layout with html copied from the main site.  This shared layout is used for the top and bottom (header and footer) of the site I'm working on.  However, I don't want to use a copy of that layout and html -- I want to actually pull in the layout & css from www.company.com so that when a change is made to that content on www.company.com, it's reflected on guest.company.com.

So, for example, the bottom "footer" area of www.company.com is contained in a footer html tag, and I want to display that content on guest.company.com.

How can this be done in MVC4 EF?

Comment: You can easily include the css from the main site with an absolute path in the link tag.  The HTML is a whole different story.  If you cannot make any changes to the code/structure of the parent site, then your only option would be to download the parent page using the WebClient class for example, parse the data and fetch only the parts you are interested in and output on your page.  If you can make changes to the parent site, you need to provide support there for fetching individual components of that site.  Using a webservice for example.

Comment: ok, I got the css part.  For the html part -- I could contact the person who has access to www.company.com.  But can you give me an example of what needs to be done on that site, and what I'd need to do on my side?

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick fool-proof way to do this.

The quick way to get the HTML is making a webrequest call from your code and get the html and take what you need from it (i.e. header and footer). Have a look at [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) for an example of how to perform this. With that, you don't need "the other side" to do anything.

Having said that, it's potentially more complicated than that. As mentioned in the comments, css path should be made absolute. But there could be images (both within html and css). Also, if header and footer run any javascript, they need to be included in the page as well. You could of course include every single JS file that is referenced in the www.company.com page but there are sometimes JS run on the page. Your webrequest call wouldn't run the JS. In order to make sure all the javascript is run and the FINAL HTML is produced, you can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

As you have probably noted, it could turn into a lot of work depending on what's on the header/footer. In my experience, a potential solution would be to have an FTP location that www.company.com copies the header/footer and their assets in. You can pull it from there every 24 hours or something.